# getting error while fetching old asset data after updateing business network using composer

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Old Asset model:

asset PurchaseOrder identified by order_Id {

```
o String order_Id

o String asset_ID

o String asset_Name

o String order_Desc    

o String order_Quantity

o String supplier_Id
```

}

Updated Asset model as :

asset PurchaseOrder identified by order_Id {

```
o String order_Id

o String asset_ID

o String asset_Name

o String order_Desc    

o String order_Quantity

o String supplier_Id

o String supplier_Name
```

}

then updated business network using composer-cli command.

Now, When I am trying to fetch(GET) old asset data using composer-rest-server API, I am getting following error:

{

"error": {

```
"statusCode": 500,

"name": "Error",

"message": "Error: Instance org.suppchain.PurchaseOrder#o2 missing required field supplier_Name",

"code": 2,

"metadata": {

  "_internal_repr": {}

},

"stack": "Error: Error: Instance org.suppchain.PurchaseOrder#o2 missing required field supplier_Name\n    at /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.5/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:434:17"
```

}

}

If we are updating business network, I think, We should able to fetch old data. is there way to fetch old asset data after updating business network using composer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You broke model compatibility by making an incompatible change to your model. The old instances are no longer compliant with your model and cannot be deserialized.

You should update your model and make the new `supplier_Name` property optional or give it a default value.

For example:

```
asset PurchaseOrder identified by order_Id {

o String order_Id

o String asset_ID

o String asset_Name

o String order_Desc    

o String order_Quantity

o String supplier_Id

o String supplier_Name optional
}
```

Or:

```
asset PurchaseOrder identified by order_Id {

o String order_Id

o String asset_ID

o String asset_Name

o String order_Desc    

o String order_Quantity

o String supplier_Id

o String supplier_Name default="UNKNOWN"
}
```

Comment: Thank You Dan, 

Can you share guidelines of updating business network without breaking compatibility? 

how to make property optional?

Comment: That is a much more general question. Please post as a separate question. Thanks.